# Set first frame of video as thumbnail automatically Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint 2013 if i have uploaded a video and not set the thumbnail then i get the rill image as thumbnail. Also the images preview folder in designer for respective video does not contain any _t & _w folder. I want to understand if there is any was to automatically set the first video frame as thumbnail, if the user has not set any thumbnail.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such kind of support, not out of the box

check this thread for more info

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/possible-to-set-the-default-image-of-a-video-to-a-snapshot-of-the-video